# Load properties file from XML in Java 1.4

Tags: java

I load properties file in java:

```
            input = new FileInputStream("props.xml");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.loadFromXML(input);
```

But now I need to make the same in `Java 1.4`? Unfortunately `loadFromXML` is available only from `java 1.5`. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Make use of XML parsers.

Comment: You can use JDOM Parser to parse props.xml. Here is one [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_jdom_parse_document.htm) which shows how to use JDOM Parser